# run ROS2 in two vs code remote containers

Tags: ros, ros2, docker, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I tried to run to ROS2 two nodes in different containers as described here: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Guides/Run-2-nodes-in-single-or-separate-docker-containers.html?highlight=container (I used foxy instead of eloquent). Everything works just fine.

Then I started two instances of vs code and opened the workspace in a remote container (based on the same image as above). In the first remote container I start the talker, in the second remote container I start the listener. Unfortunately they don't find each other. Does anyone have an idea what might be the solution?

Thanks a lot
Jeremy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380547/run-ros2-in-two-vs-code-remote-containers/) by [**Jeremy**](https://answers.ros.org/users/76193/__jeremy__/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2021-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution of the problem. The issue is that Fast-DDS comes with SharedMemory transport by default which doesn't work in this case. A solution can be found here: https://answers.ros.org/question/370595/ros2-foxy-nodes-cant-communicate-through-docker-container-border/.

---

Originally posted by [**Jeremy**](https://answers.ros.org/users/76193/__jeremy__/) with karma: 53 on 2021-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0